# uncaught exception: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to change the tab color on click

```
  $("ul.tabs").tabs("> .pane");
```

but it is throwing the error

```
uncaught exception: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method '> .pane'
```

Could somebody help me with this what is this error?

Comment: why you think it will help you to set colors ?

Comment: what tab system (plugin) are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward as the exception says. Your tabs must be initialized before you can work on them. So initialize them.

```
function(){
$("ul.tabs").tabs();
}
```

or simply by using

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs().tabs($("div.panes > div"), action);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what do you expect to get using this code, but it's wrong.
You shouldn't pass selector as an attribute for `.tabs()` method.
Look at the [jQuery UI Tabs API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization is invalid. The `("> .pane")` argument part is trying to call a method in the tabs namespace, which certainly does not exist.

Also you initialize tabs method on the div containing the list (ul), not the ul itself.

Assuming html-structure:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    // the list items
  </ul>
    // tab content divs (all with class="pane")
</div>
```

Something like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs li').bind('click', function() {
   // change bg color to 'teal' of all divs with class name '.pane' inside #tabs div
   $('#tabs').find('.pane').css('background-color', 'teal');
});
```

Read more on [jqueryui.com/tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)